# Render JSF component based on user role

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How do I render JSF components based on a logged in user's role? I know the external context exposes the principals, but how should I do the rendering properly in JSF? In JSP it would be something like

```
<% isUserInRole(Roles.ADMIN) { %>
<button>Edit!</button>
<% } %>
```

How do I write this in JSF the best possible way? My best guess is the rendered attribute tied to a backing bean's method that returns a boolean, but that would introduce an irrelevant backing bean if I have to render some navigation items only for admins...

Glassfish V3.1, JSF 2.x

Comment: In the future, please add `[jsf-2.0]` tag to indicate that :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If your `web.xml` is declared as Servlet 3.0 (which implicitly relates to JSP/EL 2.2)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
    version="3.0">
```

then you can take benefit of being able to invoke methods with arguments in EL like as [`ExternalContext#isUserInRole()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29):

```
rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}"
```

Note that this requires a Servlet 3.0 capable container, but since you're using Glassfish 3 (which supports Servlet 3.0), it should work without any issues.

Also note that if you're using Facelets instead of JSP, then you've the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29) available as `#{request}` in EL, allowing you the following shorter expression:

```
rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}"
```

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components)
- [Conditional rendering of non-JSF components (plain vanilla HTML and template text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946985/conditional-rendering-of-non-jsf-components-plain-vanilla-html-and-template-tex)
- [JSF: How control access and rights in JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516349/jsf-how-control-access-and-rights-in-jsf/)

Comment: It is indeed Servlet 3.0, but somehow among all this fuss of the exam session I'd forgotten they added method calls to JSF... Thanks very much :)

Comment: It's not specifically JSF, it's EL (those `#{}` things) which counts. If you run JSF 2.0 on for example Servlet 2.5 (which implies JSP/EL 2.1), it won't work. It's introduced in JSP/EL 2.2.

Comment: I've defined roles for each user using JDBC Realm. But the above expression always returns "false" for any user. Do I need to add some other thing to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

In response to @wasimbhalli, there are two reasons I have found that the expression would always return false:

1. The role name is case sensitive.
   `rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}"` may return `false`, but try
   `rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.isUserInRole('admin')}"`, or rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.isUserInRole('Admin')}".
2. You have to define your roles in both `web.xml` (or as annotations) and map it in `glassfish-web.xml`.

The following is how to specify a role in `web.ml`

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </security-role>
</web-app>
```

The following is how to map the authentication group to the role in `glassfish-web.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name> <!-- name defined in web.xml or annotations -->
    <group-name>admin</group-name><!-- name from authentication mechanism -->
  </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

In my testing it was necessary to do the mapping even when the names were the same, as I show in my example code.  Also in my testing, I tried to only define the mapping and only to define the role in `web.xml`, and neither worked.  I needed both, as specifying the role name in the correct case.

Answer (score 0):

Store role in session attribute and just compare that using rendered attribute.

e.g. `rendered="#{yoursessionbean.userRole == Roles.ADMIN}"`

Comment: That was one of my ideas at first, but the user can have an infinite number of roles based on his groups. Would only really work if the user only had one role...

Comment: @TC1 - agree, then you will have to go for a method call or wait if any other solution comes.