# Conditionally displaying JSF components

Tags: jsf, components, conditional-rendering

First, I am new to Java EE, came from a strong ASP .NET development background.
I have gone through the net, and I might miss this but it seems like there is no simple and straight-to-the-point tutorials on how I could connect backing bean class to a JSF components.

A good example is like this, currently I am trying to create a JSF page where there is a set of links as menu bar and a set of forms. What I am planning to do is, when clicking a link, a particular form will be rendered.

In ASP.NET, I could easily retrieve the element and then set the attribute to be displayable. I am wondering if there is easy way (heck, even any way) to do this in JSF.

The forms is already in the page, it is just a matter of setting the "render" attribute to true when I click a particular link.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Yes, use the `rendered` attribute.

```xml
<h:form rendered="#{some boolean condition}">
```

You usually tie it to the model rather than letting the model grab the component and manipulate it.

E.g.

```xml
<h:form rendered="#{bean.booleanValue}" />
<h:form rendered="#{bean.intValue gt 10}" />
<h:form rendered="#{bean.objectValue eq null}" />
<h:form rendered="#{bean.stringValue ne 'someValue'}" />
<h:form rendered="#{not empty bean.collectionValue}" />
<h:form rendered="#{not bean.booleanValue and bean.intValue ne 0}" />
<h:form rendered="#{bean.enumValue eq 'ONE' or bean.enumValue eq 'TWO'}" />
```

Note the importance of [keyword based EL operators](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#operators) such as `gt`, `ge`, `le` and `lt` instead of `>`, `>=`, `<=` and `<` as angle brackets `<` and `>` are reserved characters in XML. See also this related Q&A: [Error parsing XHTML: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338538/error-parsing-xhtml-the-content-of-elements-must-consist-of-well-formed-charact).

As to your specific use case, let's assume that the link is passing a parameter like below:

```xml
<a href="page.xhtml?form=1">link</a>
```

You can then show the form as below:

```xml
<h:form rendered="#{param.form eq '1'}">
```

*(the `#{param}` is an implicit EL object referring to a `Map` representing the request parameters)*

#### See also:

- [Jakarta EE Eutorial - Chapter 9. Expression Language](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-tutorial/#expression-language)
- [How to show JSF components if list is not null and has size() > 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360687/how-to-show-jsf-components-if-list-is-not-null-and-has-size-0)
- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)

Answer (score 15):

In addition to previous post you can have

```
<h:form rendered="#{!bean.boolvalue}" />
<h:form rendered="#{bean.textvalue == 'value'}" />
```

Jsf 2.0

Comment: Such a small addition is not worth a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

we can render a component in the form, for that we will use 'rendered' attribute

This attribute takes true/false. If the expression evaluates to a true then the specified component will be rendered otherwise it wont render in the screen.

Ex: I want to render a button for some condition.

```
<p:commandButton id="addCommentsBtn"
    value="Add Comments" title="Add Comments"
    rendered="#{backingBean.booleanResultOrVariable}">
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: This is correct, but the question was about rendering, not disabling. Showing information that the user is not allowed to see doesn't get better if you just disable it.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I have modified my solution

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. It's on a Q&A site not necessary to repeat an already given answer upon agreement. Just delete it.