# JSTL c:choose c:when not working in a JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jstl

**Consider the following *jstl* choose:**

```html
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{AuthMsgBean.rw['2'] ne null}">
        Display Text
    </c:when>

    <c:otherwise>
        <ph:outputText id="pan" value="Component pan could not be created." />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

---

*AuthMsgBean = Bean*

*rw          = Map*

*'2'         = Key*

---

**Question:**

When I simply display the `#{AuthMsgBean.rw['2'] ne null}` value it displays fine (true), but once I try to parse the value to the `<c:when test=""/>` the when tag re-acts as if the test is always false.

If I put true in the test (`test="true"`) the Display Text is displayed.

Could it be that the `<c:when>` tag is evaluated before the `#{AuthMsgBean.rw['2'] ne null}` expression?

If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: if you write `$` instead of `#` it should work: `<c:when test="${AuthMsgBean.rw['2'] ne null}">` - (i use it here in a project some time)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSTL and JSF do not run in sync as you'd expect from coding. During JSF view build time, it's JSTL which runs from top to bottom first to produce a view with only JSF tags. During JSF view render time, it's JSF which runs from top to bottom again to produce a bunch of HTML.

Apparently the `#{AuthMsgBean}` is not present in the scope when it's JSTL's turn to run. That can happen when the tags are placed inside a JSF iterating component such as `<h:dataTable>`.

Regardless, you do not want to use JSTL here. Make use of the JSF `rendered` attribtue.

```html
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty AuthMsgBean.rw['2']}">
    Display Text
</h:panelGroup>
<h:outputText id="pan" value="Component pan could not be created." rendered="#{empty AuthMsgBean.rw['2']}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-html-elements)

Comment: I want to make a generic component using a tag (as in file.tag). Would this also be a problem with dataTable?

Comment: Not if it's a Facelets tag or a JSF (composite) component, but you're lost with "plain vanilla" JSP tags. If you're using Facelets, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-component

Comment: Nice answer. Personally I like this component in some cases:
http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/utils/switch.jsf