# JSF invalid behavior with jstl foreach with different jsf version

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, pagination, jstl

I am not really sure how should I describe the problem.
I am currently learning JSF, and today tried to implement something like ajax reloaded table with pagination.

Here is my code in JSF:

```
<c:forEach var="pageNo" begin="0" end="${adapter.pagesNumber}">
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{adapter.currentPage == pageNo}">
        <li class="active"><h:commandLink value="#{pageNo+1}" disabled="true" /></li>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <li><h:commandLink value="#{pageNo+1}" action="#{adapter.setCurrentPage(pageNo)}">
                <f:ajax render=":#{cc.attrs.tableId} @form" />
            </h:commandLink></li>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

And I am using JSF from:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

My intention was to have buttons with page numbers, with currently active page button highlighted and disabled (no same page reloading).

Now, first screenshot shows my view before any action: (first page):
[image]

Lets say I clicked on page number 6,

And now, when I use JSF with version

```
     <version>2.2.4</version>
```

I got expected result:
[image]

But when I switch on versions above e.g.

```
     <version>2.2.5</version> // tested up to 2.2.11
```

I'm getting something like this:
[image]

After I've clicked on page no 9 i got another "pagination" sequence:

```
1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 6 10 11
```

but the current page in left bottom corner says it's 9th page. Table content is valid too.

Does anyone have ever faced with situaton like this or what am I doing wrong, if the same code works totally different with different JSF versions? What can be a reason of such weird behavior?

Comment: Please post your mcve (see [ask]) here instead of on pastebin

Comment: I've found later that there might be inconsistence while using JSTL with JSF resulting with unexpected behavior such as this, yet it still does not really explain why with version 2.2.4 it works (or at least it tries to work) expected way, and with > 2.2.4 not.

Comment: What you post is not an mcve. It is a snippet. And yes it is strange, but it might be because of other improvements that something that worked (but was not specifically designed to work) stops working when other improvements were made. Did you try `ui:repeat` btw?

Comment: With 'other improvements' I mean in jsf in general

Comment: I understand. Actually, I found my solution by [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7437930/4115083). Now I was just curious, why it worked before switching on newer version. Thank you.

Comment: Wait :) Although having this in a composite component is a bit awkward (better use a tagfile), it should work nonetheless. I myself suspect the `<c:forEach begin end>` from being the cause (as potential unexpected side effect of [this 2.2.5 fix](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-3084)). What if you prepare an integer array and just use `<c:forEach items>` instead? In any case, what exactly have you replaced based on that answer? Only the `<c:choose>` or also the `<c:forEach>`?

Comment: As for the tagfile, I'm still learning and didn't get there yet. Passing indexes or array has the same result. Solution to this problem (not sure if proper) was to remove c:choose, and add to html tags `rendered` attirbute with proper expression.

Comment: @invader92: can you pleasecreate your own answer with what you did...?

Answer (score 0):

Solution for the problem which worked for me was remove the

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when>
    ....
</c:choose>
```

tags, and just put the content of `c:when` and `c:otherwise` with adding an attribute `rendered` which expects boolean expression eg.

```
<c:when test="#{page.currentPageNumber == pageNumer}">
    <h:commandLink ... />
</c:when>
```

replaced with:

```
<h:commandLink rendered="#{page.currentPageNumber == pageNumer" ... />
```

The root cause is I guess execution order of JSTL and JSF, pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7437930/4115083).