# How to show a component by the controller?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I need to register an user and after that I would like to call a `<rich:popupPanel>` for example to show the error or successful message with an icon.

```html
<rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="false" autosized="true" resizeable="false">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Simple popup panel" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
        <h:outputLink value="#"
            onclick="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;">
                X
            </h:outputLink>
    </f:facet>
    <p>Any content might be inside this panel.</p>
</rich:popupPanel>
```

How do I do that after the validation of the register process in my controller ?
I could call a `<h:message>`, but I think a popupPanel with some icon and the status message would be more appropriate to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you'd just set some (boolean) toggle or a specific object property in the bean's action method which is then used in the `rendered` attribute of the containing component in question. Here's an example with a simple boolean:

```java
private boolean success;

public void submit() {
    // ...

    success = true;
}

public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
}
```

with

```html
<rich:popupPanel rendered="#{bean.success}">
     ...
</rich:popupPanel>
```

You can also set some object property and then check if it is not empty or null. E.g. when the `User` is successfully saved after registration and thus got an ID from the DB:

```html
<rich:popupPanel rendered="#{not empty bean.user.id}">
     ...
</rich:popupPanel>
```

Note: in the particular case of your `<rich:popupPanel>`, you can also use the `show` attribute instead of `rendered` attribute.

```html
<rich:popupPanel show="#{bean.success}">
     ...
</rich:popupPanel>
```

The only difference is that when `show` is `false`, the component is still rendered, but then with CSS `display:none;` so that it is visually hidden in the HTML DOM tree, so that you can redisplay it with just JavaScript.

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-html-elements)

Comment: thanks for you help. But now if I put this success in a SessionScope, it always apperars the box.. any idea how I show the message to the user after his sign up and then after set to false the success attribute ?

Comment: Don't put request/view scoped data in the session scope. Put request/view scoped data in the request/view scope. See also http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes

Comment: Thank you mate, you gave a an insight =] , you're the best