# Hide/Show form depending on selectOneMenu value change

Tags: jsf-2, drop-down-menu, hide, show

I have a page with a `<h:selectOneMenu>` and I want to show some fields or others depending on the chosen value of the selectOneMenu. Is this possible and if so, how?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, this is surely possible. Just bind the dropdown's value to the `rendered` attribute of the components to be shown/hidden. Here's a kickoff example.

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.item}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select..." />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="one" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="two" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="three" />
        <f:ajax render="@form" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.item == 'one'}">
        <p>This will be shown if the selected item equals to "one".</p>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.item == 'two'}">
        <p>This will be shown if the selected item equals to "two".</p>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.item == 'three'}">
        <p>This will be shown if the selected item equals to "three".</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

The `<h:panelGroup>` is just examplary. It can be every JSF HTML component, such as `<h:inputText>` or even another `<h:selectOneMenu>`.

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-html-elements)

Comment: I've been working on this, there's an option in my **selectOneMenu** where I want to display a **<t:tree2>** to list files on a dir I've already the code for the tree, and test it isolated, but when I put that same code in one of the options it does not get rendered.

Comment: Can I nest a form within a form?, I mean, replace the `<h:panelGroup>` for `<h:form>`.

Comment: No, that's invalid in HTML, so you should also not do it in JSF.

Comment: Maybe thats why it isnt rendering. So I just add the **tree2** code without a the form tags?

Comment: As long as you don't nest forms.

Comment: Hi. If I get rid of the **<h:panelGroup>** tags, and I put outside **<h:form>** three forms that will correspond to the options in the **selectOneMenu**, can I render the new forms using ajax like `<f:ajax render=":form1 :form2 :form3">` or `<f:ajax render="@all"` ?? Which one is better? Is this a good practice?

Comment: My answer was just a kickoff example to give you new insights. You can do with it whatever you want. You can replace `<h:panelGroup>` by any JSF HTML component which supports the `rendered` attribute. You can position them everywhere you want. As long as it suits your functional requirements. If you worry about performance, run a profiler. If you have a new question, ask a new and concrete question by `Ask Question` button :)

Comment: @BalusC do we need `<f:ajax render="@form" />`? what its doing?