# Using Ternary Operator to implement else if in EL - jsf

Tags: jsf, if-statement, primefaces, el, ternary-operator

I have an application being developed in jsf 2.0, primefaces and using Eclipse Kepler IDE. I need to display a string value in dataTable for long value. There could be 6 possible values from 1 to 6. i have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125139/the-representation-of-if-elseif-else-in-el-using-jsf) question to solve my issue but i cant. my code snipped is

```
  <p:dataTable var="student" value="#{studentBean.studentList}">
  <p:column headerText="Class">
    <h:outputText value="#{student.studentClass == 1? 'One' :
                           student.studentClass == 2? 'Second' :
                           student.studentClass == 3? 'Third' :
                           student.studentClass == 4? 'Fourth' :
                           student.studentClass == 5? 'Fifth':
                           student.studentClass == 6? 'Sixth':''}" />
  </p:column>
      ....
```

i also tried:-

```
   student.studentClass.equals(1l) and  student.studentClass.equals(1L)
```

but no luck. What am i doing wrong

Comment: So it's a `long`? What do `#{student.studentClass}` and `#{student.studentClass['class']}` print?

Comment: #{student.studentClass} prints 1 , 2 etc for which i need to show One, Second ...

Comment: if you're calling the backing bean anyway why don't you return the value from there?

Comment: You still haven't told what `#{student.studentClass['class']}` prints. The answer depends on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this approach work too?

```
<h:outputText rendered="#{student.studentClass == 1}" value="One" />
<h:outputText rendered="#{student.studentClass == 2}" value="Two" />
 ...
<h:outputText rendered="#{student.studentClass == 6}" value="Six" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer adding a simple change in the model, say:

Class Pojo/Entity

```
public class Student{

   ...

   // Add transient annotation only if is an entity class
   @Transient
   private String valueToShow;

   public String getValueToShow(){
     if("1".equals(this.studentClass){
       return "One";
     } else if("2".equals(this.studentClass){
       return "Two";
     }
       ...
  }

}
```

Then, add this change to the xhtml file (JSF Page):

```
<p:dataTable var="student" value="#{studentBean.studentList}">
  <p:column headerText="Class">
    <h:outputText value="#{student.valueToShow}" />
  </p:column>
  ....
```