# Render other selectOneMenu components after selection of one selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I want to have multiple `<h:selectOneMenu>` that are displayed by selection of main `<h:selectOneMenu>`

example which is not working

```
<h:form id="selectForm">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="main" value="#{bean.main}">
         <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
         <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
         <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
         <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
         <f:ajax render="hotelSearch"/>
    </selectOneMenu>
    //this one is displayed if main is greater than 1
    <h:selectOneMenu id="2" rendered="main>1">
         <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
         <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
         <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
         <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    //this one is displayed if main is greater than 2
    <h:selectOneMenu id="3" rendered="main>2">
         <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
         <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
         <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
         <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make it a valid EL expression `#{}`.

*(**update**: code example is updated to reflect the new functional requirement to make it to work without the need for a managed bean)*

```
<h:form id="selectForm">
    <h:selectOneMenu binding="#{mainMenu}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
        <f:ajax render="@form"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:selectOneMenu rendered="#{mainMenu.value gt 1}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>

    <h:selectOneMenu rendered="#{mainMenu.value gt 2}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="1"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="2"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="3"/>
        <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="4"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

Note that I used `gt` instead of `>` as it's an illegal character in XML. You can find all EL operators in the [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html).

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-html-elements/4870557#4870557)

Comment: Thanks it works but i was hoping to do it without managed bean. but its fine. Thanks for link it's very useful.

Comment: You can also do it without a managed bean. You just haven't asked that as such :) I've edited the answer.