# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in jsf.js.faces?ln=javax.faces

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, syntax-error

I am getting the below JavaScript error when I'm trying to access the application.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in  jsf.js.faces?ln=javax.faces

The browser is loading, but page is not displayed.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in jsf.js.faces?ln=javax.faces

This will happen when the server returned a HTML document while the browser tried to download the mentioned JavaScript file (which is necessary for a.o. the functioning of `<h:commandLink>` and `<f:ajax>` in JSF 2.x).

You probably already know that HTML documents usually begin with a `<` and a JavaScript file absolutely not. Inspecting the HTTP traffic monitor and the actual HTML response should give clues as to what exactly it returned. Press F12 in Chrome/Firefox23+/IE9+ to see it. Perhaps it's a HTTP 4xx error? 401 unauthorized? Or 403 forbidden?

That can in turn happen if your (homegrown) security/login framework is badly configured. This problem is in turn not related to JSF itself. Basically, you need to fix/reconfigure it allow requests on `/javax.faces.resource/*`.

#### See also:

- [JSF page style missing when using login filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526574/jsf-page-style-missing-when-using-login-filter/)
- [Exclude css & image resources in web.xml Security Constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696204/exclude-css-image-resources-in-web-xml-security-constraint/)
- [HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied (CSS blocked?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484312/http-status-403-access-to-the-requested-resource-has-been-denied-css-blocked/)