# How to hide elements in JSF?

Tags: jsf

Is it possible to hide a `div` etc based on a condition (like you do in rendered attribute with EL) without having to wrap it in a `<h:panelGrid ...>` etc with a rendered attribute? It ruins my layout. I just need it for the logic, not the layout.

Comment: I wonder who voted for close...

Comment: Why not using `h:panelGroup`? It will be rendered as `<div>` (under some conditions).

Comment: The close vote is just a close as duplicate. Click `close` link to see it yourself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

first of all you should not wrap your elements with `h:gridPanel` which results in html `table`

instead you should wrap with `h:panelGroup` which results in `span` in html code , you can also add `layout="block"` to `h:panelGroup` to make it rendered as `div`

second you dont not use jstl when hiding `div` instead do something like this

```
<div style="display:#{(myBean.hideSomeDiv)?'none':'block'}">My Div Content</div>
```

or

```
<h:panelGroup styleClass="#{(myBean.hideSomeDiv)?'hide':''">My Span Content</h:panelGroup>
```

where in css file add this :

```
.hide { 
    display: none;
}
```

**INMO** you always better hide in JSF with `rendered="#{myBean.renderCondition}"`

Take a look at BalusC over here [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870557/617373)

Comment: True, rendered is the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do this:

```
<div style="display:#{yourBean.property}"></div>
```

Where yourBean.property would return 'none' to hide the div

Comment: I was looking at the JSTL `if` etc, is that not better? And how would I use that if it is?

Comment: Don't know if it is better. The best is to use rendered as Daniel stated here below