# Checking Session Access in xhtml JSF

Tags: java, session, jsf, authorization

I'm making a system for asset management.there three categories of user in the system, the Administrator, Subadmin, and limited user.Administrator can do anything, Subadmin only served to verify the data and the limited user can only see just finished data / View Data

in the database, **access rights** characterized by number.Administrator = 0, SubAdmin = 1, and a limited user = 2.

to enter the system, each user must login, at the time of login, **access rights** saved into session. the problem, how do I check the session in servlet file (. xhtml)? for example there is data in the DataTable. there is menu "edit", "delete", and "Verify". if admin is logged on, then the menu "edit, delete" will appear in the table row, if SubAdmin  logged on, then just appearing menu "verify ", and if the limited user is logged on, the menu does not appear.

Should I check servletnya session at the file, or is there another way? how ?

Thanks much..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a XHTML file is not a [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) file. It's a [Facelets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info) file. Facelets is a XML based view technology.

As to your concrete question, just determine it in the JSF component's `rendered` attribute. If the boolean condition evaluates `false`, then JSF simply won't render the component (and also not process it upon submit, so you're also safe against tampered requests).

Assuming that the logged-in user is as an `User` javabean available in EL scope as `#{user}`, and has a `hasRole()` method taking a `String` and returning a `boolean`, then you could do so:

```html
<h:commandButton value="delete" rendered="#{user.hasRole('admin')}" />
```

There are variations, like having just an `isAdmin()` method returning `boolean`:

```html
<h:commandButton value="delete" rendered="#{user.admin}" />
```

Or having a `getRoles()` method returning a `Collection`:

```html
<h:commandButton value="delete" rendered="#{user.roles.contains('admin')}" />
```

You could if necessary also use an integer `0` instead of string `admin`, but that's less self-documenting.

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components)

---

Do however note that you're basically homegrowing authorization. You could also consider using Java EE builtin [container managed authentication](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncas.html) and authorization. You could then use [`HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29) to authorize users. It's much like the `User#hasRole()` suggestion:

```html
<h:commandButton value="delete" rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('admin')}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

When used [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.2.x/reference/html/ch13s09.html) in a web application, your problem is easily solved with the help of special tag:

```
<sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ADMINISTRATOR">
    <h:commandButton value="edit" />
    <h:commandButton value="delete" />
</sec:authorize>
<sec:authorize ifNotGranted="SUBADMIN">
    <h:commandButton value="verify" />
</sec:authorize>
```

To do this just add in the namespace of your page:

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
```

And connect this [library](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/downloads.html) to your project.

You can also learn other helpful [benefits](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/features.html) of Spring Security which you can use.