# condition to disable commandLink jsf2 PrimeFaces

Tags: parsing, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to disabled a commandLink with this condition:
   `<p:commandLink id="buttonchoix" value="choisir" disabled="#{editCommandController.result < car.stock}" />`

but it generated for me this error (in French):

> Error Parsing /vues_admin/editCommand.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 88] La valeur de l'attribut "disabled" associé à un type d'élément "null" ne doit pas contenir le caractère '<'

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `lt` (less than) instead

```
<p:commandLink id="buttonchoix" value="choisir" disabled="#{editCommandController.result lt car.stock}" />
```

also , take a look at next **BalusC** answer over here [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4870557/617373)