# Declare and use variable in JSF2 xhtml page

Tags: jsf-2

I am using `<s:set var="buttonText" value="getText('person.button.add')"/>` in JSTL to use buttonText variable to set text.

**Someone tell me how to accomplish this in JSF EL please?**

Question asked here [IF-ELSE condition in JSF form. Need to know right approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591618/if-else-condition-in-jsf-form-need-to-know-right-approach/13595477#comment18649867_13595477) but told to ask as a separate question.

**EDITED:**

I already added a link above for detail but here is again.

I am using JSTL like in struts2 project

```
 <s:if test="person==null || person.id==null || person.id==''">
                <s:set var="buttonText" value="getText('person.button.add')"/>
            </s:if>
            <s:else>
                <s:set var="buttonText" value="getText('person.button.edit')"/>
            </s:else>
```

I want to use same approach in JSF2 but with Expression Language. I am saving value in a variable called `buttonText` and accessing it below somewhere like `#{buttonText}`. I need solution to how to write variable in `EL` and use it. Hope its clear.

I need solution to `<s:set var="buttonText" value="getText('person.button.add')"/>` line of code only.

Thanks

Comment: please clear about your question? What do you actually want to know?

Comment: **WARNING** do NOT use `<ui:param>` as mentioned in 1st option of the currently high rated answer! ALWAYS use `<c:set>`, no excuses.

Comment: Why, @BalusC? Is that because the expression get reevaluated every time it's used?

Comment: @bruno: It's explained in the abovelinked dupe. In a nutshell: it's NOT where the `<ui:param>` is originally intended for. It's exactly the same problem as trying to use a hammer to fasten a screw: it might work in some circumstances, but it's utterly the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `ui:param`

In the following ways:

```
<ui:param name="buttonText" value="#{myBean.MyValue}" />
```

or

```
<ui:param name="buttonText" value="someText" />
```

or

```
<ui:param name="buttonText" value="someText#{myBean.MyValue}" />
```

and use later on like this

```
<h:outputText value="#{buttonText}"/>
```

---

Another option would be using `<c:set` in the following way

```
<c:set var="buttonText" value="#{myBean.MyValue}" />
```

But note that `<c:set` is a JSTL tag,

> JSTL tags runs during building the view (when the XHTML file is converted to
>   JSF component tree)

Also you might want to read this [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets… makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3343681/617373)