# Hide and show components depending on h:selectOneMenu value

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a page with a `<h:selectOneMenu>` and I want to show some fields or others depending on the chosen value of the menu. Is this possible and if so, how?

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="productname" value="#{product.productname}" required="true"> 
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="select" itemValue="null" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Detetgent" itemValue="Detergent"/>  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dishwash" itemValue="Dishwash" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Powder" itemValue="Powder" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Liquid" itemValue="Liquid" />       
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:panelGroup rendered="Detergernt">
    <p>This will be shown if the selected item Detergent.</p>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup >
    <p>This will be shown if the selected item Dishwash.</p>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup >
    <p>This will be shown if the selected item equal to powder.</p>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:panelGroup >
    <p>This will be shown if the selected item equals to Liquid.</p>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Are you using libraries or only plain JSF 1.2 / 2.0 ?

Comment: am using jsf 2.0 and Primefaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="productname" value="#{product.productname}" required="true"> 
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="select" itemValue="null" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Detetgent" itemValue="Detergent"/>  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dishwash" itemValue="Dishwash" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Powder" itemValue="Powder" />  
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Liquid" itemValue="Liquid" />    
    <p:ajax event="onselect" update="selectedOp" listener="#{product.updateSelectedValue}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:panelGroup rendered="{product.updateSelectedValue ne null}" id="selectedOp">
    <p>This will be show selected value</p>
    #{product.updateSelectedValue}
</h:panelGroup>
```

This is how you can display the selected value from drop down on the page. I assume that you are using PrimeFaces, so using an ajax event tag `<p:ajax>` inside `<h:selectOneMenu >`. Also adding the condition on `<h:panelGroup rendered="{product.updateSelectedValue ne null}">`, so that it will be displayed when selected value is other than `null`.

Comment: This will fail for the reason as mentioned in the 2nd "see also" link of my answer. Plus, `<p:ajax>` is't required at all. The standard JSF library already offers the `<f:ajax>`. The listener method has also no use in this particular case.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to check in the `rendered` attribute if `#{product.productname}` returns the desired value. In order to update all those components, you should add an `<f:ajax>` to the menu which updates a common parent component —which is *always* rendered— of all conditionally rendered components.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="productname" value="#{product.productname}" required="true"> 
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="select" itemValue="null" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Detetgent" itemValue="Detergent"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Dishwash" itemValue="Dishwash" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Powder" itemValue="Powder" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Liquid" itemValue="Liquid" />
    <f:ajax render="groups" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:panelGroup id="groups">
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{product.productname == 'Detergent'}">
        <p>This will be shown if the selected item Detergent.</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{product.productname == 'Dishwash'}">
        <p>This will be shown if the selected item Dishwash.</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{product.productname == 'Powder'}">
        <p>This will be shown if the selected item equal to Powder.</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{product.productname == 'Liquid'}">
        <p>This will be shown if the selected item equals to Liquid.</p>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components/4870557#4870557)
- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w/9010771#9010771)

Answer (score 0):

Yea, you can achieve this . Please do paste your page , so that it is easy for me to explain on the page itself.

The idea is to use an `<a4j:outputPanel>` as a container and  `<h:panelGrourp layout="block" rendered="#{}">` as a wrappper for the fields which are need to hidden.
The selected value of `selectOneMenu` will be used in the `rendered` attribute of `<h:panelGroup>`.