# Meaning of empty from, empty create etc. in expression language

Tags: jsf-2, el

I came across some `.xhtml` files where for some components the expression language used was like `rendered="#{empty from}"`, `rendered="#{empty create}"` etc.

I know that `empty` is an operator in EL, used to check whether a value is null or empty, but I did not understand the meaning of above mentioned ELs.

Can somebody explain to me what above EL's mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rendered` attribute is a signal whether JSF should generate HTML for the component or not. If it evaluates `false`, then it won't generate HTML for the component (nor for its children). The `#{empty form}` will evaluate `false` when the `#{form}` is not null nor empty.

Simple as that. You can find another examples of boolean expressions here: [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components/4870557#4870557)

Comment: I know the behavior of rendered attribute and usage of empty operator. But I am not able to understand what `from`,`create` words mean. Does these have some special meaning?

Comment: It are just variables in EL scope, like managed beans or view/template  parameters. You can name them whatever you want. The `#{form}` could for instance be just a `@Named @Produces public Form getForm()` or an `<ui:param name="form">`.