# JSF render not working properly

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Everything inside f:view `<f:view rendered="#{p.statusmsg!=null}">`,`<f:view rendered="#{p.picstatus!=null}">` and `<f:view rendered="#{p.videostatus!=null}">` is getting executed whether the value of statusmsg,picstatus or videostatus is null or not

1)getMoreStatusUpdate.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
   <div id="content">
      <h:form>
         <ui:repeat var="p" value="#{statusBean.moreStatusList}">                   
            <f:view rendered="#{p.statusmsg!=null}">
            //Status content    
            </f:view>
            <f:view rendered="#{p.picstatus != null}"> 
            //Picture Status Content                            
            </f:view>  
            <f:view rendered="#{p.videostatus != null}">
            //Video Status Content
            </f:view>                   
         </ui:repeat>
      </h:form>
   </div>
</h:body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<f:view>` [doesn't](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/view.html) have a `rendered` attribute.

This attribute is only supported on [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) based tags, which is all tags of the [`h:` library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/tld-summary.html) and a few of the `ui:` library including [`<ui:fragment>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/fragment.html).

Just replace `<f:view>` by `<ui:fragment>`.

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components/4870557#4870557)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was hoping you would answer, that way I knew my problem is going to get solved at one go. I am currently struggling a lot to design a social network site and your post and suggestion on internet have been really helpful.