# security in Jsf2 guessing and modifying url should not be allowed

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have an application up and running. I have a page addstudent.xhtml page where the user adds the student details.When user finishes adding and submits he will be redirected displaystudent.xhtml page.

My question is when user directly types on browser 
localHost:8081/Student/displaystudent.xhtml. Page is displayed with blank values.This should not happen. How do I prevent this even though he types on browser.

Both the files addstudent.xhtml displaystudent.xhtml pages are in web-inf folder. I am using Jsf2, primefaces 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `displaystudent.xhtml` an include file which you render conditionally in `addstudent.xhtml` depending on whether the student is successfully added.

E.g., assuming standard JSF:

```
<h:panelGroup id="addStudent" layout="block">
    <h:form rendered="#{empty bean.student.id}">
        <h2>Add student</h2>
        <h:inputText value="#{bean.student.name}" />
        ...
        <h:commandButton value="Add" action="#{bean.add}">
            <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":addStudent" />
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>

    <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{not empty bean.student.id}">
        <h2>Added student</h2>
        <dl>
            <dt>Student name</dt><dd>#{bean.student.name}</dd>
        </dl>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

*(simplified; you could of course split off the add student to `<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/displaystudent.xhtml">` and so on)*

The button, whereby the `add()` method should return `void` or `null`, re-renders the `<h:panelGroup id="addStudent">`. If the student was successfully been added in the DB, then it should have a non-empty ID. This will cause the form to be hidden and the results panel to be shown.

#### See also:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components/4870557#4870557)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/15523045#15523045)