# Hide jsf commandLink in certain condition

Tags: jsf

I want to hide `commandLink` if following condition exists:

`verifyTxnList.resolved` where `resolved` has value `Y` then I want to hide `commandLink` else  show commandLink

```
<h:commandLink value="#{verifyTxnList.resolved}">
       ...
       ...                
</h:commandLink>
```

like following :

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox  id="resolveTxn" value="#{verifyTxnList.checked}" disabled="" rendered="#{!verifyTxnList.checked}"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the component to render its HTML output (if the rendered condition is `false`), you can use the `rendered` attribute. In this case, you can't have the component shown, without having the page re-rendered and the rendered condition evaluated to `true`.

```
<h:commandLink rendered="#{verifyTxnList.resolved == 'Y'}" />
```

More info about `rendered`:

- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components/)

Comment: You can also wrap the link in a container (h:panelGroup for example) and ajax-update that container to conditionally show or hide the link.

Comment: First option is completely wrong. This attribute doesn't exist on the `<h:commandButton>` at all. See also http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html for a list of all valid attribtues. Please remove this misinformation, then I'll remove the downvote. In future answers which you can't answer off top of head, please test yourself first in a true JSF playground project before posting.