# if else conditional in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I tried apply rendered in order to check for if else conditional in JSF. (ref: [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components/4870557#4870557))

This part is my JSF index.html

```
<p:commandButton value="Update Hidden Label" action="#{carForm.updateBool}" />
<h:outputText value="Text A" />
<h:outputText value=" Text B" rendered="#{carForm.booleanValue}" />
```

This is my java class

```
private boolean booleanValue;

public boolean isBooleanValue() {
    return booleanValue;
}

public void setBooleanValue(final boolean booleanValue) {
    this.booleanValue = booleanValue;
}

public void updateBool() {
    booleanValue = true;
}
```

when I tried click on "Update Hidden Label", it would update the booleanValue in java class to true, however in index.html page "Text B" is still not appear yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also you need to update page fragment with `<h:outputText value=" Text B" rendered="#{carForm.booleanValue}" />`

You can use `<p:panel id="textPanel"></p:panel>` and put your code there.

And add `update` parameter to `p:commandButton` with value `textPanel`, like this `update="textPanel"`.

```
<p:panel id="textPanel">
  <p:commandButton value="Update Hidden Label" action="#{carForm.updateBool}" update="textPanel" />
  <h:outputText value="Text A" />
  <h:outputText value=" Text B" rendered="#{carForm.booleanValue}" />
</p:panel>
```