# How to integrate CASBIN with JSF

Tags: jsf, spring-security, authorization, casbin

I have a web application with JSF. For authentication we are switching to OAuth and for authorization we are switching to CASBIN. Having said that I did not see any TAGLIBS from CASBIN which can be used in the JSF pages directly. Any idea how to tackle this problem? 
I have no experience with Spring security either, would that be a better option to go with JSF?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you (think you) need tags. The rendered attribute of components works great for most cases. I never missed specific tags.

Comment: Do you mean conditional "render" tag usage? Could you please give an example if I did not understand correctly. Thanks :) You can directly post as an answer too, I think what you are saying mightbe sufficient :)

Comment: I am from Casbin team. Please send an issue here: https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin/issues and we will have staff answering your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462 (posting the first sentence of your comment in google would have given you the link above... ;-)

Comment: Ok thank you :) Now I know what u meant.