# JSF h:outputText rendered condition based on user role

Tags: security, jsf

I have to render outputText in JSF based on user role
outputText box is:

```
<h:outputText id="citizenaddress" value="#{customerView.customerCurrentAddress}" escape="false" rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.userInRole('isabletoGetCitizenAddress')}"></h:outputText>
```

web.xml is:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

and exception is:

```
javax.el.ELException: /info/citizenInfo.xhtml @42,193 rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.userInRole('isabletoGetCitizenAddress')}": Method userInRole not found
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Render JSF component based on user role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747321/render-jsf-component-based-on-user-role)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is [isUserInRole(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29).

You are likely conflating the expression rules for bean properties with the syntax for methods.

I believe the expression should be:

```
#{facesContext.externalContext.isUserInRole('isabletoGetCitizenAddress')}
```

Comment: @odgiivH The question still seems to use `userInRole` instead of `isUserInRole`.

Comment: A shorter one is `#{request.isUserInRole('isablttoGetCXitizenAddress')}`.

Comment: Thank you man would you like to answer this question here is my main problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257183/java-ee6-security-issues

Comment: when jsf doesn't render component, how to fill the gap where component were supposed to place. Component just disappeared and other component does fill the it's space. I just need to leave its space empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the double quotes for `isabletoGetCitizenAddress` to single quotes.
`<h:outputText id="citizenaddress" value="#{customerView.customerCurrentAddress}" escape="false" rendered="#{facesContext.externalContext.userInRole('isabletoGetCitizenAddress')}"></h:outputText>`