# creating dynamic menu in JSF according to user credentials

Tags: jsf

My question is how to dynamically create menu bar from the database according to user credential using JSF 2.0 ? kindly provide me some hints or links which can be of help. Thanks

Comment: There's plenty of help on this topic. Try reading this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747321/render-jsf-component-based-on-user-role). User roles are your friends in this case.

Comment: Simply using the `rendered` attribute with one bean managing the user roles?

Comment: @awesum, have you tried something?

Comment: @Alexandre Lavoie How to do it? I have three tables in database 

1)Menu 

2)Users 

3)menu_users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using Third party component libraries with JSF.
You could go for [Primefaces](http://primefaces.org/).
It has a different varieties of Menu Bars [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubar.jsf).

Here using `p:menu`, you can create menu using [Menumodel](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/model/class-use/MenuModel.html). that model can be changed from ManagedBean based on the user Privileges.
Here is the Primefaces [Menu Model](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu.jsf) Example,where last **Programmatic Menu** is created using MenuModel.
Here is the Primefaces Blog [Link](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=2594).

Comment: By dynamic menu , I mean a particular user should be shown some menu items or in other words he can navigate to some of the pages using menu bar

Comment: @BalusC can u provide any help in this regard?

Comment: See the left correct symbol on the answer? @awesum click that. Accepting answer which helped you, will increase your reputation, too. You have 0% acceptance ratio, so improve it :)